# Nested Map data in Terraform

Tags: terraform

Let's say I have an string type variable called "env" (the value can be "dev" or "production")

With the following data, how can I get the value of setting1 for the first element in "dev" or "production"?

```
locals{
   environments = {
      dev = {
         "hello001" = {
            setting1 = "abc"
            setting2 = "def"
            setting3 = "ghi"
         }
         "hello002" = {
            setting1 = "jkl"
            setting2 = "mno"
            setting3 = "pqr"
         }
      }
      production = {
         "hello003" = {
            setting1 = "abc"
            setting2 = "def"
            setting3 = "ghi"
         }
         "hello004" = {
            setting1 = "jkl"
            setting2 = "mno"
            setting3 = "pqr"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I tried with

```
local.environments[var.env][0].setting1
```

but getting the error "This value does not have any indices"

Comment: If the keys do not matter for the specific environment maps, then you could convert those to lists. Essentially, could you convert this from `map(map(map(object(...string...)))` to `map(map(list(object(...string...)))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all the error message I get is slightly different:

```
│ Error: Invalid index
[...]
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value. An object only supports looking up attributes by name, not by numeric index.
```

but I guess that's because of a different Terraform version. I have 1.0.7.

### Explanation / context

Nevertheless, the problem is exactly as [mentioned by Matt in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69347873/nested-map-data-in-terraform#comment122572006_69347873) - maps in Terraform HCL don't support integer-indexing. I.e. you cannot do a `[0]` on a map. Some programming languages offer that possibility, Terraform does not.

See:

```
locals {
 my_dictionary = {
   "one" = 1
   "two" = 2
 }
}
```

If I try `local.someMapping[0]` it fails with the same error.

### Way out

It depends on how you want to access your hello001, hello002s, etc.

Either change the most-inner map to a list, e.g.

```
locals{
   environments = {
      dev = [
         {
            setting1 = "abc"
            setting2 = "def"
            setting3 = "ghi"
         },
         {
            setting1 = "jkl"
            setting2 = "mno"
            setting3 = "pqr"
         }
      ]
      production = [
         {
            setting1 = "abc"
            setting2 = "def"
            setting3 = "ghi"
         },
         {
            setting1 = "jkl"
            setting2 = "mno"
            setting3 = "pqr"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and then you can `local.environments["dev"][0].setting1`

... or stick with maps, but then you need to iterate over the map somehow, e.g. use `for_each` to define a resource for each `hello00x`:

```
locals{
   environments = {
      dev = {
         "hello001" = {
            setting1 = "ami-0c55b159cbfafe1f0"
            setting2 = "t3.micro"
         }
         "hello002" = {
            setting1 = "ami-01d7c2b5c4fc0218a"
            setting2 = "m4.large"
         }
      }
   }
}

resource "aws_instance" "my_server" {
 for_each = local.environments["dev"]
 
 ami = each.value.setting1
 instance_type = each.value.setting2

 tags = {
  Name = each.key
 }
}
```

Here I defined a single `aws_instance` for each of the two hellos.

Comment: I just like to drop my gratitude for this solution. Thank you very much.